# Click on Load more element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I have a news website to scrape. But after scraping the first page, I need to click on "load more" which is a link to view other news and then scrape. Where I am encountering an issue is that I can't seem to click on "load more" because it doesn't have a "href". I have tried all possible resources, but they have all worked to no avail. Please, kindly help me out with this. Thank you. I have attached the code I used and the link to the website.

Code trials:

```
pip install webdriver-manager

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = 'https://www.legit.ng/tag/road-accidents-in-nigeria/'
driver.get(url)
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Entertainment")
link.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element with text as ***Load more*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *XPATH* and `text()[contains()]`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.legit.ng/tag/road-accidents-in-nigeria/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()[contains(.,'Load more')]]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `contains()`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.legit.ng/tag/road-accidents-in-nigeria/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(., 'Load more')][./p[text()]]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: First, thank you for your comment. However, I got the following error while running the code;


ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="c-action-link__text-container">...</div> is not clickable at point (686, 458). Other element would receive the click: <svg class="c-action-link__border" width="100%" height="100%">...</svg>
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.99)